# NOT NULL not working on primary key with auto increment

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, notnull

Why `NOT NULL` in column definition does not work if that column has both `PRIMARY KEY` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Tested on MySQL 5.6.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

```
id
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as seen in the mysql page:

> If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign
> NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers

[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

That is the expectec behaviour.